# Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError in android device

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show javascript Google's map in android device using ionic framework. Map was shown successfully in browser but not in Android device. Error receiving in Android is

"Your site URL to be authorized: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/map"

But I've added below two URLs already in allowed address in Google developer console under Browser key.

```
file:///android_asset/www/index.html
file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/map
```

And i've added below permissions in manifest.xml also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

But still issue exists. Can someone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a discussion about the [same error](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-api-key-for-file/56324/4) in the ionicframework site about this.

[A cordova plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) was referenced that was said to have worked better than JavaScript API.

Answer (score 1):

For `file://` referers, you need to replace the `file:/` with `__file_url__` .

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key-restrictions) states:

> `file://` referers need a special representation to be added to the Key restriction.
>
> The `file:/` part should be replaced with `__file_url__` before being added to the Key restriction. For example, `file:///path/to/` should be formatted as `__file_url__//path/to/*`. After enabling `file://` referers, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.